# margin property for Alloy element in Titanium

Tags: margin, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I have an Alloy item template for row in listview as below. I want to layout 3 labels in row in vertically and margin-top 5dp each others. How can I do that for both Android and iOS?

```
<Templates>
   <ItemTemplate name="row" height="100dp">
         <Label bindId="name"/>
         <Label bindId="weight"/>
         <Label bindId="distance"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</Templates>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file, adjust it like so

```
<Templates>
   <ItemTemplate id="templateRow" name="row" height="100dp">
         <Label id="name" bindId="name"/>
         <Label id=weight" bindId="weight"/>
         <Label id="distance" bindId="distance"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</Templates>
```

In your tss file:

```
"#templateRow":{
     layout: "vertical"
},
"#name":{
    top: '5dp',
},
"#weight":{
    top: '5dp'
},
"#distance":{
    top: '5dp'
}
```

Alternatively:

```
<Templates>
   <ItemTemplate layout="vertical" name="row" height="100dp">
         <Label bindId="name" top="5dp"/>
         <Label bindId="weight" top="5dp"/>
         <Label bindId="distance" top="5dp"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</Templates>
```